# Aplicação Xamarin.Android com Bing Maps

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Vi que a Bing Map API não fornece um SDK para Android. De que forma eu poderia criar um app `Xamarin.Android` com Bing Maps?

Comment: Você obrigatoriamente precisa usar Bing Maps ou poderia ser um Google Maps, por exemplo? Ou ainda outro SDK?

Comment: Estou penando no bing map por ser uma solução Microsoft e certamente ter uma melhor integração com as demais ferramentas (visual studio, .net, xamarin, etc)

Comment: Certo, porém não precisa se preocupar quanto a isso. Já utilizei o Google Maps API para Xamarin.Android e funcionou perfeitamente. Atualmente utilizo outro SDK que na minha opinião é ainda melhor que o do Google. Irei colocar uma resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Após uma troca rápida de informações com o Matheus (autor da pergunta), percebi que não há a necessidade explícita do uso do `Bing Maps`. Então, irei apresentar duas APIs de mapas para `Xamarin.Android` que, na minha opinião, são as melhores e mais confiáveis atualmente.

- **Google Maps API**
- **Mapbox API**

### Google Maps API

Usar o aplicativo `Maps` é ótimo, mas às vezes você deseja incluir mapas diretamente em seu aplicativo. Além do aplicativo de mapas integrado, o Google também oferece uma API de mapeamento nativa para o Android. A API do Google Maps é adequada para casos em que você deseja manter mais controle sobre a experiência de mapeamento. As coisas possíveis com a API do Google Maps incluem:

- Programaticamente alterar o ponto de vista do mapa;
- Adicionar e personalizar marcadores;
- Marcando um mapa com sobreposições.

Diferentemente da agora desativada API do Google Maps para Android v1, a API do Android do Google Maps v2 faz parte do Google Play Services. Portanto, é necessário atender a alguns pré-requisitos obrigatórios antes que seja possível usar a API do Google Maps para Android em um aplicativo `Xamarin.Android`.

Além dos pacotes `NuGet` necessários para a API do Google Maps, é também necessário instalar o `Google Play Services`.

A parte talvez mais complicada é a de configurar seu aplicativo para poder receber o Google Maps API. É necessário criar uma conta nas APIs do Google, gerar uma chave e *linkar* a mesma com o seu aplicativo. Mas não se assuste, tem tudo bem documentado.

**Leitura obrigatória**

- [Google Maps API no Xamarin.Android](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api)

### Mapbox API

O Mapbox Maps SDK para Android é um conjunto de ferramentas de código aberto para criar aplicativos de mapeamento para dispositivos Android com grande flexibilidade para estilo visual e personalização.

Com o Mapbox Studio, você pode personalizar todos os aspectos do mapa, desde ajustar as cores até ocultar ou exibir camadas específicas, até decidir quais informações deseja apresentar no mapa.

Escolha um estilo de mapa ou personalize completamente seu próprio mapa e dados. Os mapas são renderizados em uma taxa de quadros super alta - permitindo que os mapas respondam com fluidez aos comentários dos usuários ou a eventos com script.

A API do Mapbox para Xamarin.Android é uma opção tão boa quanto (na minha opinião ainda melhor que) o Google Maps API.

Digo isso pelo fato de ter precisado de alguns recursos que o Google Maps não oferece em seu SDK para Xamarin, como por exemplo a utilização de um mapa *offline* sem data limite para expiração e a customização avançada de mapas que o Mapbox API oferece.

O único empecilho que encontrei foi que versão para `Xamarin.Android` da API do Mapbox não possuía todos os métodos implementados devido ao fato de que a mesma foi feita pela equipe de desenvolvimento do Xamarin e os mesmos esqueceram de portar todas as funcionalidades.

Trocando emails com a equipe responsável pela API (Xamarin), eles me informaram da existência de outra biblioteca que foi portada por outra empresa e que a princípio funciona perfeitamente. O link para essa API/SDK está no item "leitura obrigatória" logo abaixo.

**Leitura obrigatória**

- [Documentação](https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/)
- [SDK para Xamarin.Android](https://blogs.naxam.net/using-mapbox-in-xamarin-android-7ffe2466f5f7)

### Ainda deseja utilizar Bing Maps?

Caso ainda assim deseje utilizar o Bing Maps no seu aplicativo, a única modificação que terá que fazer é alterar seu projeto `Xamarin.Android` para um projeto `Xamarin.Forms`.

Há uma API do Bing Maps disponível para `Xamarin.Forms` que utiliza a API do Google em conjunto.

**Leitura obrigatória**

- [Iniciando com Bing Maps e Google no Xamarin.Forms](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Getting-Started-with-0ccd1c5b)

### Conclusão

Dado a experiência que tive com ambas as APIs, eu recomendo a utilização do Mapbox. Além de ser muito mais customizável que o Google Maps API, o suporte da empresa em caso de dúvidas e problemas é muito bom e a documentação da API é bem completa.

Estou utilizando o Mapbox há dois anos e os mapas da API estão tanto em um aplicativo `Xamarin.Android` quanto em uma aplicação .NET Core. Até agora não obtive nenhum tipo de problema, muito pelo contrário, só elogios.

**Fonte (além das informadas anteriormente)**

- [Mapbox Mobile](https://www.mapbox.com/mobile/)

Comment: Muito bom. Ótimas referências! +1 porque não pode +10

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Muito obrigado pelo feedback. Comentários assim nos motivam ainda mais a ajudar a comunidade.